# FB Connect with Devise + Omniauth get error: hostname was not match with the server certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I'm running into a problem, where I keep getting this error after entering my Facebook username/password.

`OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError`

hostname was not match with the server certificate"

I'm on Mac 10.6.6, Ruby 1.9.2-p180, Rails 3.0.7 with XCode installed, using Devise and Omniauth to do this Facebook connect.

How can I get this over with?

Comment: Can you post the callback URL that you had  used while registering your app in facebook and also the URL that you are trying to use in your local machine?

Comment: @Aroop: yes the Site URL/Canvas URL: http://localhost:3000/ and the ran locally, the URL is http://localhost:3000

Comment: Make sure that you have a tailing / for your canvas URl.

Comment: @Aroop: yes sure, even I didn't add, by clicking "Save" button, Facebook will add it automatically. Any idea?

Comment: I had this error a while back but I don't remember what I have done to fix it. Can you please post the complete trace that way I might recollect what I did to fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer on my own, it may help others who have the same issue:

This error is because of SSL Certification checking. I followed some online tutorials to create cert files on Mac OS but it took too much time so finally I decided to bypass the SSL checking on development machine by adding these lines to ./config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
if Rails.env.development? 
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE 
end
```

Comment: Could the one who made a downvote tell me the reason? At least this helps people to test on local machine without being confused with SSL configuration.